# XmlHttpRequest vs jQuery

Tags: jquery, xmlhttprequest

I am new to both javascript and jQuery. I am developing a page in which I have generated page's whole html from code. In the page, there in a textbox to post messages and for each message comments can be posted. Now when I post a new comment or delete a comment I need to do database call.
I know 2 method to do it from js

> 1. do xmlhttprequest
> 2. do ajax call from jQuery.

Can anybody suggest me which method will suite my requirement?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Each browser has their own implementation of XmlHttpRequest. Using a framework will minimize the headache of cross-browser differences and quirks, especially if you are very new.

Comment: thanks ... i have one  method in same page which calls wcf service to delete the comment. can you please tell me that how to call that method using jquery[ajax] coz whatever examples i saw in that there is url of a page... then how to call method of that page as well as i dont want to refresh the whole page..

my method also returns CommentId based on that i have to generate some html and write it in div... 

can you please suggest me any good article to see sample code for the same?

Comment: I think you can find those questions already answered here in Stackoverflow... if you can't find answers, just raise them up and we'll try to help you...

Comment: @Dominic but in terms of performance bruh, which is faster xmlhttprequest or jquery?

Comment: 7 years later, this is no longer correct. Almost every browser supports XHR now.

Answer (score 3):

xmlhttprequest is not working through cross-browser, for example [some IE versions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XMLHttpRequest#Support_in_Internet_Explorer_versions_5.2C_5.5_and_6), so best option is jQuery's ajax call.

Comment: [Compatibility](http://caniuse.com/#search=XMLHttpRequest) for IE is for 10+. In my case I'm developing specific media related app with html5, web workers, etc. IE is not part of the game for now.

Comment: @YOU Isn't behind $.ajax method xmlhttprequest?

Comment: I believe things changed since 8 years ago. There was browsers without xmlhttprequest at that time and jQuery changed.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery itself will be using XMLHTTPRequest object. What it provides will be a wrapper for the functions. So if you want to avoid the burden of writing javascript that targets various browsers then you can opt for jQuery.

Answer (score 1):

At least today jQuery isn't a clean or even a fast solution, from this test the results for me in mobile or desktop shows that jQuery are, at least, 80% slower than XHR2: https://jsperf.com/xhr-vs-jquery-ajax-vs-get-vs-fetch

Comment: Amen. People think it's weird to use native JavaScript when jQuery is "easier" until the benchmarks.